# How to use custom MySQL queries in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I am working on cakephp now.Please explain the process of custom mysql query in cake php.
we have to write query by using

```
$this->Model->query();
```

and I return this to controller.In controller,i loaded the model in particular function and i called the function and set that function to view like this

```
$this->set('post',$this->User->get());
```

is it correct process?please explain the code ...

Answer (score 3):

What query do you want to write this way? It is possible to write nearly all queries using the CakePHP ORM. Using the query building functions of CakePHP is the prefered way of doing it.

All data fetching an manipulation should be done in a model as well. See [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Here is a complete **model method** to fetch an user record based on its id OR slug.

```
public function view($userId, $options = []) {
    $defaults = array(
        'contain' => array(),
        'conditions' => array(
            'OR' => array(
                $this->alias . '.' . $this->primaryKey => $userId,
                $this->alias . '.slug' => $userId,
            ),
            $this->alias . '.email_verified' => 1
        ),
    );

    $result = $this->find('first', Hash::merge($defaults, $options));

    if (empty($result)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__d('user_tools', 'User not found!'));
    }

    return $result;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function view($userId = null) {
    $this->set('user', $this->User->view($userId);
}
```

**Alternative but NOT preferred mode method** to fetch te data

```
public function view($userId, $options = []) {
    $result = $this->query(/* Your query here */);

    if (empty($result)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__d('user_tools', 'User not found!'));
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct, let me eleborate it in more detail

**1st Solution**

In your controller

```
$arrayTemp =array();
$arrayTemp = $this->ModelName->query(' Your Query String ');
$this->set('post',$arrayTemp);
```

**2nd Solution**

In your model class

```
function returnDate(){
   return $this->query('Your Query String')
}
```

In Controller class

```
    $arrayTemp = $this->ModelName->returnDate();
    $this->set('post',$arrayTemp);
}
```

Comment: 2nd one is what you are doint exactly in question. You are welcome